# cmd cant get what is listening to port 8080

Tags: java, windows, exception, cmd, port

been having an issue for a while where I cannot start java servers due to port 8080 already being in use. Searching around I have found answers which tells me to find what process is occupying the port, and kill it. Sounds easy enough.

However:
No matter what netstat or other command I type trying to display process reveals anything on port 8080! if I try `netstat -ano | find "8080"`, it returns nothing. If I restart my computer, and start the server quickly, it works, but its really annoying to develop like this. Its obvious something is binding the port, but I just can't figure what.

I am sorry if this seems like a duplicate, but the question differs by having a hidden process taking the port.

This is on Windows 10, build 15063

Comment: If I remember correctly I had a similar issue years ago with skype that for some reason started a server that I think was listening on port 8080.

Comment: @Daniel, I don't have Skype running on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

use the following command should be:

```
netstat -ano |findstr 8080
```

Comment: Returns nothing

Comment: Have you update your JRE ?
It is because when the JRE updated, the JRE directory should be changed accordingly.

Comment: Tried updating, didn't help

Comment: No, Does your server update JRE automatically?
It is because after the JRE update, a new JRE directory will be created and the old JRE directory will be empty. So, your java server cannot find JRE to start server, therefore you need to point to the new JRE directory to start your java server.

Comment: No. I am attempting to install Jenkins currently, but get thrown the BindException.

Comment: No, there are not

Answer (score 2):

Use `Resource Monitor` on windows to see network stats and ports (tab Network)

To open the `Resource Monitor` type `resmon.exe` into the Start Menu search box and press Enter.

Or, you could open the Start Menu and go to "All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Resource Monitor".

If you prefer using your keyboard, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: It does not show port 8080 on any of the listenings ports or processes

Comment: looks like you have got a virus. Try scan on viruses or reinstall your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can see which port is curently using by 
If you are using window
Start->search for resource monitor->then network tab in resource monitor

Comment: Nothing there uses port 8080

Answer (score 0):

if you use Tomcat server go to the tomcat location -->bin
and execute the command file "shutdown"

Comment: Dont use Tomcat

Comment: what server u use?